# Angular 2 Why can't I use interpolation on attributes marked with @Attribute?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a component written like so:

```typescript
@Component({
selector: 'ams-text',
templateUrl: './text.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./text.component.scss']
})
export class TextComponent extends ElementBase<string> {

  constructor(
    @Attribute("name") public name : string,
    @Attribute("label") public label : string,
    ) {}
}
```

However, if I try and use it like this:

```html
<ams-text name="someName_{{ someNumber }}" label="{{someLabel}}"></ams-text>
```

Angular2 throws this error:

```
Template parse errors:  Can't bind to 'label' since it isn't a known property of 'ams-text'.
1. If 'ams-text' is an Angular component and it has 'label' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ams-text' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Now 3 things:

Generally I don't need binding to name or label because they aren't going to change over the lifetime of the component.  I might want to initialize them from a variable using interpolation, but while they are on the screen that variable isn't going to change its value.  Which is exactly what interpolation buys me.

I'm going to typically initialize these values with static text, and using interpolation on these attributes is rare, but does happen.  Again why interpolation makes sense over using `@Input` as it is cumbersome to use static text with `@Inputs`.

Finally it has no problem with interpolation in the name attribute.  If I remove the interpolation from label attribute it doesn't complain about name and actually works as I expect.

I've tried several variations:

```html
<ams-text name="someName_{{someNumber}}" attr.label="{{someLabel}}"></ams-text>
<ams-text name="someName_{{someNumber}}" attr-label="{{someLabel}}"></ams-text>
```

Without success.

So why can't I use interpolation in a field declared as an `@Attribute` on a component?  Can I fix it?

Comment: both `name="{{...}}"`  and `[name]="..."` produce almost the same code inside [updateDirectives](https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-property-bindings-update-in-angular-39c0812bc4ce) function in view definition so you can treat that as equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Attribute()` means that the value is injected when the component is created. It's a one-time action and happens before change detection gets a change to resolve bindings (`{{...}}`).

If you want to use binding, use an `@Input()` instead

```typescript
constructor() {}

@Input("name") public name : string;
@Input("label") public label : string;
```

With these inputs also the error messages will go away, because they are telling you that you are binding to properties that don't exist, which isn't the case anymore when above code is added to the component.

Comment: But if I use `@Input` it's not going to accept static values as naturally as a regular attributes in html do.  It seems odd that this works for regular html attributes but when I put them on a component it fails.  Again it works for name which is a big indicator there is a way to make this work.  I really don't have to detect changes as I described.  I just want to initialize it once from a variable.

Comment: "initialize it once from a variable" means binding, which means you need inputs.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "if I use @Input it's not going to accept static values as naturally as a regular attributes in html do."

Comment: With regular attributes I can do someAttribute="Hey this is static", with Input it's an expression so I'd have to do [someAttribute]"'HeyThis is static'" with extra ticks.

Comment: `someAttribute="Hey this is static"` works as well. Only when you add `[]` the value needs to be an expression.

Comment: Ok good point.  I think you ultimately are right (as usual). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom html tags then it will report that Template parse errors.Add Schema on your module to suppress this message for components.

```typescript
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule ,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core'; 
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,


  ],
  schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [],
  providers:[],
  entryComponents: [

  ]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Also you can use `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` to suppress all attribute validation.